# open new window using javascript which will restrict user from using its parent window

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I want to open a new window using window.open method which will restrict user to use its parent window till the new window is not closed. User will not be able switch back to parent window while child window is still open.

How can i do it using javascript? please guide me..

Answer (score 2):

If you want the popup window to be modal (i.e. to disable its parent window until it's closed), you might want to use [window.showModalDialog()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog) instead of [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Note, however, that you cannot use [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.opener) from a modal dialog box (it will always be `null`) unless you explicitly pass a reference to the parent window in the second argument to `showModalDialog()` and get it back using [window.dialogArguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.dialogArguments).